# When I added sharedpreferences to checkbox then shows "<asynchronous suspension> " error on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I added sharedpreferences to checkbox then shows " " error and "[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value" error on flutter. How I resolve it?

error ..
[image]

checkbox flutter code

```
class ConstantScreen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const ConstantScreen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ConstantScreen2> createState() => _ConstantScreen2State();
}

class _ConstantScreen2State extends State<ConstantScreen2> {
  final _preferencesService = PreferencesService();
  var isChecked = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _populateFields();
  }

  void _populateFields() async {
    final settings = await _preferencesService.getSettings();
    setState(() {
      isChecked = settings.isChecked!;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(Config.app_background3), fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: ListView(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 5, left: 0),
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Expanded(
                    child: ListTile(
                      minLeadingWidth: 1,
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.brightness_1,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 10.0,
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        Config.app_agree2,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'yes',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Checkbox(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
                      (states) =>
                          BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.blueAccent),
                    ),
                    value: isChecked,
                    onChanged: (value) => setState(() => isChecked = value!),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 0),
                child: Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 160.0,
                    height: 35.0,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        shape:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                            side: const BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: isChecked ? displayMessage : null,
                      child: const Text('next'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void displayMessage() {
    if (isChecked == true) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ChildGrowScreen()),
      );
      _saveSettings;
    } else {}
  }

  void _saveSettings() {
    final newSettings = Settings(isChecked: isChecked);

    print(newSettings);
    _preferencesService.saveSettings(newSettings);
  }
}
```

model

```
class Settings {
  bool? isChecked;

  Settings({bool? isChecked});
}
```

preference_services page

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'constant2_model.dart';

class PreferencesService {
  Future saveSettings(Settings settings) async {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    await preferences.setBool('isChecked', settings.isChecked!);

    print('Saved settings');
  }

  Future<Settings> getSettings() async {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final isChecked = preferences.getBool('isChecked');

    return Settings(isChecked: isChecked);
  }
}
```

I can't understand my error. How I resolve it?
In my code I used a separate model and to save data I used the preference_service file.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explaining: you're using a null-check operator (the `!`) on a variable that can be `null`, and the error is thrown because at runtime that variable is `null` indeed.

The `!` tells your program that, despite being of a nullable type (because of the `?` after its type), you're sure that at runtime it will never become `null`...but that happens to be a lie, so flutter throws the error.

I suggest some debugging to discover why that variable becomes `null`, especially in any line of code where you're using `!`.

EDIT

Either here `isChecked` is `null`

```
void _populateFields() async {
  final settings = await _preferencesService.getSettings();
  setState(() {
    isChecked = settings.isChecked!;
  });
}
```

or here `value` is `null`

```
  value: isChecked,
  onChanged: (value) => setState(() => isChecked = value!),
```

or here `isChecked` again is `null`

```
await preferences.setBool('isChecked', settings.isChecked!);
```

and that goes against your code, since for the compiler putting `!` after a variable means "this variable will not be `null` here" (I think I got all the `!` in your code).

Hence the error: you have to check why `value` or `isChecked` are `null` when they shouldn't be.

Comment: yeah that's true but I can't understand what's the error I have already upload the code if you know error can you tell me.

Comment: yeah I tried it bro now error resolved but I still sharedpreference not working..Thank you bro for your help

Comment: I don't know if that's your case, but usually, when I have to display some stuff coming from `shared_preferences` or other `async` methods, I use `FutureBuilder` so I know that the widgets will be displayed only when the loading has ended.

Answer (score 1):

In your `ConstantScreen2` class inside `_populateFields` change this:

```
if(settings.isChecked != null){
   setState(() {
      isChecked = settings.isChecked;
   });
}
```

and in your check box do this:

```
Checkbox(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
    ),
    side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
      (states) =>
          BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.blueAccent),
    ),
    value: isChecked,
    onChanged: (value) {
        if(value != null){ // <---- add this
          setState(() => isChecked = value)
        }
    },
  ),
```

and in your `PreferencesService` inside `saveSettings` change to this:

```
if(settings.isChecked != null){
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    await preferences.setBool('isChecked', settings.isChecked!);
}
```

For your last issue first you call function wrong, you need add `()` to `_saveSettings`, second your PreferencesService's `_saveSettings` is a future so you needed to `await` so change your `_saveSettings()` to `future<void>` and `await` to it then navigate to `ChildGrowScreen` page. So change this:

```
void displayMessage() async {//<--- add this
    if (isChecked == true) {
      await _saveSettings(); //<--- add this
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ChildGrowScreen()),
      );
      
    } else {}
  }
```

and this:

```
Future<void> _saveSettings() {
    final newSettings = Settings(isChecked: isChecked);

    print(newSettings);
    _preferencesService.saveSettings(newSettings);
  }
```

Comment: yeah I tried it bro now the error is resolved and no error showed but I still sharedpreference is not working, I want, if close from recents and reopen the application then it should display the checkbox selected (isCheckd==true). That's not working bro haw make that according to your edits

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @DasunDola

Comment: When I added "await _saveSettings();" to "void displayMessage()" shows this error " The await expression can only be used in an async function.  Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'. "

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out, @DasunDola

Comment: now no error shows, but bro when we select the checkbox and click the next button after closing the app from recent apps and reopen it again, the  checkbox is opening as unselected.I want the checkbox to be selected when I reopen the app